# Custom Calculation in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I've the below data in my hive table.

```
    A           B       C       D   E
1   prashant   11980   1000   -50   25
2   siva       11980   1500   -25   20
3   prateek    11980   1200   -20   70
4   rahul      12001   2000   -80   20
5   rajesh     12202   2100   -25   10
6   ankit      12201   1700   -70   20
7   alok       12203   4000   -30   100
```

And I've a requirement to get data from this table to another hive table by doing some calculations(as shown below). As you can see, it has got an extra column which should get data based on the mentioned calculation.  Basically the concept is - Take output of calculation in one row as an input to next row and so on.

```
    A           B       C       D   E   F
1   prashant   11980   1000   -50   25  E1-D1
2   siva       11980   1500   -25   20  F1-D2
3   prateek    11980   1200   -20   70  F2-D3
4   rahul      12001   2000   -80   20  F3-D4
5   rajesh     12202   2100   -25   10  F4-D5
6   ankit      12201   1700   -70   20  F5-D6
7   alok       12203   4000   -30   100 F6-D7
```

I tried writing a UDAF for this but seems not working as I could not see any method to take the last row value when iterating to next row and then not sure how the terminatePartial() and merge() functions would work in case of multiple map tasks.

Stuck at this point.

I also thought of taking the data to a text file and then running mapreduce job on it but it is a bit complex as calculations would mix up in case of multiple map tasks.

Not sure how would it be possible in hadoop. Any advice would be of great help.

Comment: What's rule to produce column F, does it only depend on the values of the sample line?

Comment: @luoluo yes it only depend on the values of sample line. Rule is - Subtract values in E and D and put it in F for the first row. Then take this value of F from first row and pass it as a input to next row and calculate its F column value as  -> (Value of F from last row - value of D in current row) and so on for other rows.

Comment: `and pass it as a input to next row` this means it's not `only` depend on the same line. And in this case, It's not suitable to solve in a distribute way. Is it possible to make it `only` depend on the values of the same line?

Comment: @luoluo Yeah that's the problem. It doesn't depend on the same line, instead takes the value from previous line. Is there anything on your mind that could be implemented in hive or mapreduce for this?

Comment: To me, MR's advantage is doing job in parallel way. In your case, each job depend on the previous job, which means this only can be done within one mapper. It's definitely not a suitable case to use `hadoop`. Hive is just a wrapper of hadoop, which means hive is not suitable for this bad rule either. If possible, change your rule.